# Is it possible to use something like showHelpMessageIfInvalid() on lightning:inputFields?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-design-system

I want to trigger the "complete this field" message on a lightning:inputField if it is invalid (empty value). This works fine on a normal lightning:input, but is there a way to do it on an inputField? I was experimenting with showing/hiding a div with text in it under the inputField, but I'm not sure how to get the red outline on the component.

My current approach is:

Markup:

```
<lightning:recordEditForm  objectApiName="CustomObject">
                                <lightning:inputField aura:id="customForm"
                                                      fieldName="AccountId"
                                                      value=""/>
<div aura:id="customError" class="slds-text-body_regular slds-hide">Complete this field.</div>

</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Controller:

```
if ( !( component.find( customForm ).get( "v.value" ) ) )
{
    component.find( customError ).getElement().classList.remove( "slds-hide" );
}
```

Comment: could you please share the code for your current approach? this way it will be easier to provide feedback, thanks!

Comment: Went ahead and added what I did

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using  tag inside  ? If field is required (standard/custom validation), a message is displayed.

Otherwise you can also use slds styles to display your helptext by adding the following class : slds-form-element__help
See this link for more information : https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/ (tick "error" in 'states' section on the right hand side)

I hope this will help you